# WebGL: use both texture and color buffers

Tags: javascript, webgl

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313685/webgl-enablevertexattribarray-index-out-of-range), where the OP was reporting a warning being issued when executing instruction `gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);` got me thinking: what if I want to have a scene with two (let's assume: flat) shapes in it, one with a texture and one with a uniform color? In the fragment shader's `main`, if I uncomment the second instruction and comment out the first, like so:

```
void main(void) {
    //gl_FragColor = vColor;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
}
```

the warning is still being issued, but this time in regards to the instruction `gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);`.
If I leave both uncommented, it still complains about the vertexColorAttribute because clearly it's being overridden.
So how can I have both? Am I to use two different fragment shaders? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Sorry I was certain I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *proper* way would be to have two separate shaders since you want to render either 
textured **or** colored.

At the cost of memory and execution time, you may always have color **and** texture attributes in your vertex data and use some kind of blending depending on your use case.

As you describe it you could use simple additive blending as most WebGL implementations bind a black pixel [0,0,0,255] texture as default when no texture is bound.

Thus having something like

```
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vColor + texture2D(uSampler, vTexCoord);
}
```

would render the color when no texture is bound and correctly render the bound texture when color is [0,0,0,0].

See wikipedia for an overview of various [blend modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes)

As an even more **expensive** solution you could just use a uniform as flag to indicate what "method" you want to use and branch inside the shader accordingly. This still requires all vertex attributes to be available though, also branching is quite inefficient on some platforms.

```
void main(void) {
    if (uMethod == 1)
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    else if (uMethod == 2)
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTexCoord);
    else
        gl_FragColor = vColor + texture2D(uSampler, vTexCoord);
}
```

Comment: Another method could be to pack several images into a single texture and adjust texture coordinates to show the correct region. One of those regions could be a solid red square.

Comment: This would make it quite inflexible and either requires branching and/or heavy texture coordinate transformation math, or comes with wasting a lot of GPU storage.

Comment: I don't think so, this is standard for texture atlases. You simply set you texture coordinates accordingly in the vertex buffer and then you don't need any color uniforms or attributes.

Comment: Everytime you add a mesh with another color you need to adjust the atlas as well as all texture coordinates on all meshes using that atlas...

Comment: If the OP would really only want to render using a uniform color, then well, one could drop the vertex attributes anyway and just use one color uniform inside the shader.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go for the *proper* way and add another shader.

Comment: Unfortunately, attempting to bind two different vertex shaders yields the following warning: `WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: attachShader: shader attachment already has shader`; depending on the order I attach the fragment shaders, either the one for colors or the one for textures has an exit status of -1 for the call to `gl.getAttribLocation()`... any hints?

Comment: you need to create two seperate (glsl-)"programs", one for color and one for texture. You cannot bind multiple compiled shaders of the same type to one program.

Comment: Alright, fair enough, but can I "render" more then one program on the same html canvas? I basically want to draw textured and untextured objects *together*. For the time being I'm sticking with your suggestion to use "additive blending", i.e: `gl_FragColor = vColor + texture2D(uSampler, vTexCoord)`. Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by *together* ? Of course you need to switch programs during your frame to use seperate shader programs: `ctx.useProgram(color) ... render colored primitives ... ctx.useProgram(textured) ... ctx.bindTexture() ... render textured primitives ...`